# Argument 1 passed to Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::__construct(),of Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection,Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-5

whenever I want to login my page, this error came, but I added my mongodb database with my project, what's the issue?

I just want login my page with my mongodb database, where i mentioned everything

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide the error-message and some code.